# Magento 2 : How to custom contact form

Tags: magento2, frontend, contact-form

I want to custom my contact form like this:

[image]

It must send data for user submitted via email

How can I do that?

Any help? Thank in advance.

Comment: Yes, You can make a form page as per contact.

Comment: some extension use that code. https://www.fmeextensions.com/quick-contact-magento-2.html

Comment: and for best https://magenticians.com/add-custom-field-in-magento-2-contact-page/

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below steps. 
https://magenticians.com/add-custom-field-in-magento-2-contact-page/

Answer (score 0):

you can use below code to add custom form in contact page

> create app/code/Vendor/Extension/view/frontend/layout/contact_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">    
   <body>       
       <referenceContainer name="content">
           <block class="Magento\Contact\Block\ContactForm" name="contactCustom" template="Vendor_Extension::customform.phtml" />
       </referenceContainer>
   </body>
</page>
```